# Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list' when extending ListActivity

Tags: java, android

LogCat

```
06-02 15:53:34.742: E/Trace(1188): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
06-02 15:53:36.682: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 49K, 7% free 2539K/2708K, paused 483ms, total 484ms
06-02 15:53:36.712: I/dalvikvm-heap(1188): Grow heap (frag case) to 3.666MB for 1127536-byte allocation
06-02 15:53:36.782: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1K, 5% free 3639K/3812K, paused 69ms, total 69ms
06-02 15:53:36.902: D/dalvikvm(1188): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 3639K/3812K, paused 15ms+42ms, total 123ms
06-02 15:53:37.672: I/Choreographer(1188): Skipped 49 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
06-02 15:53:37.705: D/gralloc_goldfish(1188): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
06-02 15:53:40.412: D/AndroidRuntime(1188): Shutting down VM
06-02 15:53:40.412: W/dalvikvm(1188): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{testing.android.application.three/testing.android.application.three.MainActivityNext}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188): Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ListActivity.onContentChanged(ListActivity.java:243)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:273)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1881)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityNext.onCreate(MainActivityNext.java:28)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
06-02 15:53:40.612: E/AndroidRuntime(1188):     ... 11 more
06-02 15:53:44.662: I/Process(1188): Sending signal. PID: 1188 SIG: 9
```

Comment: please post your code and explanation what's happen and what's wrong

Comment: I have, check the question.

Comment: @koesie10 No, it should be changed back to the OP and post a new question or it becomes confusing for others

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is you are trying to `extends ListActivity` and you don't have a `ListView` with

```
android:id="android.R.id.list"
```

You need to have a `ListView` in your xml with that `id`. Please add it to your xml

You can tell by the following line in your logcat

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

If you find the next line that references your `Activity` it will tell you the class and line number

```
at testing.android.application.three.MainActivityNext.onCreate(MainActivityNext.java:28)
```

So `MainActivityNext` line 28 is showing the exception.

**Note**

As stated in a comment, please don't just post unformatted logcat when asking for help. Please try to look for where the error is occurring and post relevant code along with a description of what the problem is. This one was easy to see from the error but usually we will need to see some code

You can use CTRL+K to format your code and logcat or use the coding brackets above {}

Comment: Forgive me friend, I've edited the question with the current status.

Comment: That's ok but you can't change the OP like that or it becomes confusing and useless for others. Please change it to the original and post a new question with relevant error messages and code

Comment: Yes, then accept one of these answers and post a new question. As it is, our answers don't match the cod/errors you are showing so it won't make sense for others, hence becoming useless to anyone else

Comment: Include the code in your new post that is giving error along with what the errors say and/or logcat

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16884897/unfortunately-app-name-has-stopped heres the new question if you can help.

Answer (score 2):

You have defined a ListViewActivity (I guess), but it doesn't have a `@android:id/list`. You should change the ID of your ListView like this:

```
<ListView
  android:id="@android:id/list"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
</ListView>
```

Comment: I did but still three errors are being showed. Check the edited question.